# Spreading Buttons Equally

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-linearlayout

My activity consists of 14 buttons which I try to spread equally on the screen.

I also want them to be exactly same size although one of them displays 3 digit number (rest of them have 1digit or 2) and another one have an image on it.

Those two buttons are making all of the problems because they dont want to keep the same size even when I set the weight as 1 for all of them and I dont use `wrap_content`.

Middle row is slightly lower than the others and I had to use "invisible button" for 3rd row so it looks good but I know it is lame solution.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity=""
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="#f000"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    style="@style/lineralLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button0"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background_green"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load0"
        android:text="@string/btn_0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load2"
        android:text="@string/btn_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button8"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load8"
        android:text="@string/btn_8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button40"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load40"
        android:text="@string/btn_40"
        android:textAppearance="@style/buttonText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonQuestion"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="loadDontKnow"
        android:text="@string/btn_question"
        android:textAppearance="@style/buttonText" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    style="@style/lineralLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1_2"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load1_2"
        android:text="@string/btn1_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load3"
        android:text="@string/btn_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button13"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load13"
        android:text="@string/btn_13" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button100"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load100"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_100" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ButtonCoffee"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/coffee_descr"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/coffeepng"
        android:text="@string/btn_13"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
    style="@style/lineralLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load1"
        android:text="@string/btn_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load5"
        android:text="@string/btn_5"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button20"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="load20"
        android:text="@string/btn_20" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonInfinity"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="loadInfinity"
        android:text="@string/btn_infinity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/Invisiblebutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/btn_0"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

and the style for those buttons:

```
  <style name="buttonText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_background_green</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop"> 5dp </item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp </item>
</style>

  <style name="Invisiblebutton" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/invisible_btn</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop"> 5dp </item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp </item>
  </style>
```

Comment: If you are spreading the buttons horizontally, set the widths to 0. If you are spreading the buttons vertically, set the heights to 0. Setting anything else messes with the way Android distributes the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you almost have it. If you use the attribute weightsum for your parent layouts, you can position the elements precisely. For instance:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
style="@style/lineralLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5"  >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button0"
    style="@style/buttonText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_background_green"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="load0"
    android:text="@string/btn_0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    style="@style/buttonText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="load2"
    android:text="@string/btn_2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button8"
    style="@style/buttonText"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="load8"
    android:text="@string/btn_8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button40"
    style="@style/buttonText"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="load40"
    android:text="@string/btn_40"
    android:textAppearance="@style/buttonText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonQuestion"
    style="@style/buttonText"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="loadDontKnow"
    android:text="@string/btn_question"
    android:textAppearance="@style/buttonText" />
```

Comment: weightSum is autocalculated and should only be used when the overall weight can't be inferred